# Custom swatch message 'This is a required field'

Tags: magento2, swatches, messages, configurable-swatches

Is there a way to customize the 'This is a required field' message when you don´t select a swatch option?

I want to change it to "Please select a color" and "Please select a size"

Thanks!

Comment: This is what exactly you are looking for. @max pronko has describe everything in detail here how to change custom validation with magento mixin. [Full Youtube Video Guid Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fguDL5iEd0) Thanks to Max Pronko

Answer (score 0):

This message comes from the `mage/Validation.js`

```
$.validator.messages = $.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: $.mage.__('This is a required field.'),
    remote: $.mage.__('Please fix this field.'),
    email: $.mage.__('Please enter a valid email address.'),
    url: $.mage.__('Please enter a valid URL.'),
    date: $.mage.__('Please enter a valid date.'),
    dateISO: $.mage.__('Please enter a valid date (ISO).'),
    number: $.mage.__('Please enter a valid number.'),
    digits: $.mage.__('Please enter only digits.'),
    creditcard: $.mage.__('Please enter a valid credit card number.'),
    equalTo: $.mage.__('Please enter the same value again.'),
    maxlength: $.validator.format($.mage.__('Please enter no more than {0} characters.')),
    minlength: $.validator.format($.mage.__('Please enter at least {0} characters.')),
    rangelength: $.validator.format($.mage.__('Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long.')),
    range: $.validator.format($.mage.__('Please enter a value between {0} and {1}.')),
    max: $.validator.format($.mage.__('Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}.')),
    min: $.validator.format($.mage.__('Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.'))
});
```

If you look in the dom, the attribute code is on the div that holds the size `<div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">` as a `param` `attribute-code` so you can write some JS to get the attribute code and write a more meaningful validation/error message

Comment: Thank you Haim! I was looking for this file!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage",
        "mage/validation"
    ], function($){
        $('#product_addtocart_form').mage('validation', {
            messages: {
                'super_attribute[93]': {'required': '<?= $block->escapeJs(__('Please select colour before adding to cart')) ?>'},
                'super_attribute[176]': {'required': '<?= $block->escapeJs(__('Please select size before adding to cart')) ?>'}

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here "super_attribute[93]" and "super_attribute[176]" is the attribute field name, Its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a translation for the swatches module, go to your translations file and translate the error message for the module.

```
"This is a required field.","Please select a color.", module, Magento_Swatches
```